# How to get Recently modified Method Names from a class File Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

Is there a way to find which methods were recently modified in a given class file using Visual Studio IDE 2005

Answer (score 1):

If you have source control, use source control.

Otherwise, you can use a tool like NDepend.